# MYSQL 'SELECT' and COUNT "active" user for day in user event table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

```
+----+--------------+------------+--------+
| id | user    | date(data) | type        |
+----+--------------+------------+--------+
|  3 | 5458848 | 2013-12-19 | SUBSCRIBE   |
|  4 | 5458848 | 2013-12-19 | UNSUBSCRIBE |
|  5 | 5458848 | 2013-12-20 | SUBSCRIBE   |
|  7 | 5458848 | 2013-12-20 | UNSUBSCRIBE |
|  8 | 7883870 | 2013-12-20 | SUBSCRIBE   |
|  9 | 7883870 | 2013-12-23 | UNSUBSCRIBE |
| 10 | 7883870 | 2013-12-24 | SUBSCRIBE   |
| 11 | 7883870 | 2013-12-24 | UNSUBSCRIBE |
| 12 | 7883870 | 2013-12-24 | SUBSCRIBE   |
+----+---------+------------+-------------+
```

Hello, I need to know how make query in mysql for watch how many users have active and not-active daily,

example: if one user  is SUBSCRIBE  and UNSUBSCRIBE in the same day, it mean that for that day, I have a user not-active

```
+------------+-------------+-------------+
| date(data) | active      | inactive    |
+------------+-------------+-------------+
| 2013-12-19 | 0           | 1           |
| 2013-12-20 | 1           | 1           |
| 2013-12-23 | 0           | 2           |
| 2013-12-24 | 1           | 1           |
+------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set @ac:=null;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ___active_nums;

CREATE TABLE ___active_nums(
  event_id integer,
  event_user_id integer,
  event_date  Date,
  number_of_active_users integer,
  INDEX USING BTREE (event_date)
)
ENGINE=MEMORY 
;

INSERT INTO ___active_nums

SELECT

  events.id,
  events.user,
  events.date,
  ifnull( @ac:= ( @ac + if( type='SUBSCRIBE', 1, -1) ), @ac:=if( type='SUBSCRIBE', 1, -1) ) AS active_num

FROM 
(
  SELECT * FROM events ORDER BY id
)
AS events
;

SELECT

event_date as date,
number_of_active_users,

( SELECT count(DISTINCT event_user_id) FROM ___active_nums WHERE ___active_nums.event_date <= outer_active_nums.event_date )
- number_of_active_users
as number_of_inactive_users

FROM ___active_nums  AS outer_active_nums

WHERE event_id IN ( SELECT max(event_id) FROM ___active_nums GROUP BY event_date );
```

Comment: It not work fine becouse on  2013-12-23 it give 1 user active and 0  inactive

Comment: now give 0 user active and 1 inactive, but the user inactive are 2.. in the 2013-12-23  i need to see  the users 5458848 + 7883870 inactive

Comment: updated my answer again. It's a little bit long and ugly, but it works. I hope it helps

Comment: on 2013-12-23  give 0 user active and 1 inactive, but the user inactive are 2. and in the few  days the inactive user with -1

Comment: you have one email where i can send one screnshot?

Comment: my email is dangquocvi@gmail.com

Comment: i send you email with screnshot

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN type='SUBSCRIBE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as active,
       SUM(CASE WHEN type='UNSUBSCRIBE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as inactive
WHERE (date>='2013-12-19' and date<='2013-12-24');
```

Comment: Thank you, but I had already created the same query;
This returns the sum of SUBSCRIBE and UNSUBSCRIBE, I need to know the Daily Active Users,

Comment: @ggmac23 Can you explain a little bit more about what you want? Do you mean the total number of people who subscribed and unsubscribed on the that day?

Comment: Sorry for my English, I need to see how many people I have active and inactive in a rage of dates,example: if the user '5458848 'is SUBSCRIBE and UNSUBSCRIBE in the same day, this  user will be inactive for the next few days, until this user SUBSCRIBE again

Comment: @ggmac23 You mean say from 2013-12-19 to 2013-12-24, you'd like to know the number of active and inactive users?

Comment: @ggmac23 , I edited the code, try it if it's what you want :)

Comment: Not please is not right; I need to get the following information from the query +------------+-------------+-------------+
| date(data) | active      | inactive    |
+------------+-------------+-------------+
| 2013-12-19 | 0           | 1           |
| 2013-12-20 | 1           | 1           |
| 2013-12-23 | 0           | 2           |
| 2013-12-24 | 1           | 1           |
+------------+-------------+-------------+

Comment: @ggmac23 I'd really like to help. I get it now... Hold on, I'm trying to think hard!

Comment: @ggmac23 Good question... I thought it was easy because the structure looks so easy... my bad...pretty challenging...I like this problem...I'll post my answer immediately when I come up with something...

Answer (score 0):

You need the difference between the cumulative number of subscribes and unsubscribes on each date in order to calculate whether someone has subscribed or not.  For example, the last user `7883870` has a state of "subscribe" after three events on the same day.

One way to do this is with correlated subqueries:

```
select t.user, t.date,
       (select sum(type = 'SUBSCRIBE') - sum(type = 'UNSUBSCRIBE')
        from table t2
        where t2.user = t.user and
              t2.date <= t.date
       ) netsubs
from table t
group by t.user, t.date;
```

WIth this information, we can then determine the state someone is in on a given date.

```
select date, 
       sum(case when netsubs > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as active,
       sum(case when netsubs = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as inactive
from (select t.user, t.date,
             (select sum(type = 'SUBSCRIBE') - sum(type = 'UNSUBSCRIBE')
              from table t2
              where t2.user = t.user and
                    t2.date <= t.date
             ) netsubs
      from table t
      group by t.user, t.date
     ) t
group by t.date;
```

EDIT:

I misunderstood the question.  On any given day, you want the number of users that are active or have unsubscribed up to that point.

```
select date, numacive, numusers - numactive as numinactive
from (select date,
             (select count(distinct user)
              from table t2
              where t2.date <= t.date
             ) as numusers,
             (select sum(type = 'SUBSCRIBE') - sum(type = 'UNSUBSCRIBE')
              from table t2
              where t2.date <= t.date
             ) as numactive
      from (select distinct date
            from table t
           ) t
     ) t;
```

Comment: @ggmac23 . . . Does the first query correctly accumulate the number of subscribes and unsubscribes?

Comment: as you can see in the result of query the users inactive in the day 2013-12-23 are 2..  how can I get this?